# Unity light breaking in build version

Tags: unity-game-engine, light

So in unity you can bake lights and you have to make the gameobjects static so they get a lightmap
So I did made my objects static and bake the scene light.

The result in the editor and in editor play
this is what I want
[image]

But when I build the game I get this
[image]

there is no light at all or its just spread all around the floor

The floor gameobjects are just primitives with a texture
I tried to reacreate the bug by placing some gameobjects and lights in a new scene
in both editor and build there was no problem
[image]

I used the default camera to make sure its not a issue with the camera on the play but no matter what I do it has the same effect on the previous scene.
I tried making the direct samples bigger inderect samples bigger and enviroment samples bigger
also the lightmap size bigger but nothing works.

LightMap Settings
[image]
Quality Settings
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Okay so they way to fix this is go to
**Edit > Project settings > Player**
go to other settings and disable lightmap streaming
[image]

You need to disable it because huge maps like mine generate a lot of lightmaps and streaming all of them in runtime is really slow and so the lightmaps is really low res